# Why keep existing settings in Termios serial interface

Tags: serial-port, termios

I'm using some open source software and I would like to return some of my bug fixes to the original project. The software includes a serial interface accessed using termios.h. Both the PC running Ubuntu and the peripheral device use the same configuration. I only want very basic settings for transmitting and receiving bytes: no parity checking, no flow control or XON/XOFF, no Canonical mode.
The original code only changed one flag: `uart_config.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR;`
This didn't sufficiently configure the port on the PC side, and I ended up replacing all the flag values:

`uart_config.c_iflag = IGNBRK | INPCK;
uart_config.c_oflag = NL0 | VT0;
uart_config.c_cflag = CS8 | CREAD | CLOCAL;
uart_config.c_lflag = 0;`

which works ok.
However pretty much every online code example shows setting only specific bits and leaving all other bits untouched using &= ~ or |= 
eg http://slackware.osuosl.org/slackware-3.3/docs/mini/Serial-Port-Programming

What is the reasoning behind preserving the value of some flags, values or unused bits on setup? I can't think of much to be gained, except maybe if someone can't understand the purpose of all the flags and are afraid to change them, and a lot of risk if the original settings aren't pre-configured to reasonable values.

Comment: It's for reliable and portable code. See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237). "However pretty much every online code example shows setting only specific bits and leaving all other bits untouched..." -- Then you've found the good (& IMO scarce) examples, and should emulate them!

Comment: @sawdust, thanks for your response. "you've found the good (& IMO scarce) examples, and should emulate them!" - I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: I should note that I'm only changing the value of the flags variables defined in termios, not anything else, but after posting this question I did think of some rare, tending to weird, cases where changing the entire c_iflag/c_oflag/c_cflag/c_lflag could cause problems. One scenario is where a processor only accesses ram via 32 bit reads and writes, the termios values are mapped directly to registers, and other registers are on the same bank of 4 byte wide registers. Another scenario is where an odd implementation of termios uses unused bits for something that I should be leaving alone.